# singleton-early initialization ,static field initialization and class loading

Tags: java

Conside this code:

```
class MyClass {
    private static MyClass myobj = new MyClass();

    private MyClass() {
    }

    public  static MyClass getMyobj() {
        return myobj;
    }
}
```

1)IN above code when will `myobj` get initialiazed-when `Myclass` gets loaded OR when `getMyobj()` will be called first time as `MyClass.getMyobj();`?

2) Suppose we call twice as:

```
MyClass.getMyobj();
MyClass.getMyobj();
```

will it create new `MyClass()` object on second call?

Comment: 2. No it only gets created once, because the static initializers only run once.

Comment: It gets created once when it get loaded into the JVM

Comment: You should read about the lifecycle of objects in Java. One of the first search results, seems to cover what you are interested in: [The Lifecycle of a Java Object](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/the-life-cycle-of-a-java-object.html)

Comment: It is always better to check whether the "myobj" is null or not. If null, generate it, otherwise don't

Answer (score 2):

1. When your class will be loaded
2. No , it won't create another object, it will use the already existing one

Comment: No, you can load a class without initialising it.

Comment: Tom Hawtin is right. A class won't initialise until you force it to by calling one of its methods or accessing one of its fields. If your code only calls a static method in a conditional loop, and the condition is never met during a particular run of the software, then the class will not be initialised during that run. So memory is not used by the class fields until absolutely necessary.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: considering that a static initialization block is executed only once when the class is loaded. Shouldn't this also be the case for class(static) members ? That's the logic I followed when I answered the question.

Comment: Following the logic of @user1515834, the class members of a class are initialized right before being needed for the first time. Wouldn't this be inefficient ? Wouldn't it be better to initialize all the classes needed in the current application, at the beginning, in an initialization phase right before starting the main thread of the app. If we follow this line of reasoning, if the loop is never entered in a particular run, the class doesn't even have to be loaded.

Comment: @Razvan I don't know whether this is more or less efficient. All I know is that a compliant JVM behaves according to the JLS, and the JLS says that a class is not initialised until the moment it is needed by running code. An initialisation phase which occurred at the start of a program run could never know which conditions will later be satisfied (by user input, for example) so it could never know which classes to initialise in advance.

Comment: @Razvan Class loading is hideously inefficient. (It was worse back in the earliest days of applets when each class required a new HTTP connection, and that was before Keep-Alive so a new TCP connection too.) Can't change the spec now (not until the big reset button is pushed).

Answer (score 1):

> 1)IN above code when will myobj get initialiazed

When the class is first loaded.

> 2) Suppose we call twice as:...will it create new MyClass() object on second call?

No mainly because `myobj` is static so `getMyobj()` will always return the same instance, the one created at load time.

Answer (score 1):

1. When MyClass gets loaded.
2. Even if you call it ten times, only one instance exists for MyClass.

Comment: No, you can load a class without initialising it.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline : I am talking about the specific Question the OP has asked.

Comment: And indeed specifically `MyClass` can be loaded without being initialised.

Comment: Tom Hawtin is right. See [JLS 12.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html) for the JVM rules on initialization.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out the object will be created when the class is initialised, and because the method simply returns it, no other such instances will be created in the example code.

However, if you want to do such a thing you could also create an `enum` with a single instance:

```
public enum MyClass {
   myobj;
}
```

Then code which needs to work with `myobj` can simply access the `MyClass.myobj` field while the code itself retains singleton behaviour. Of course a similar effect may be accomplished with a `public static final` field.

The enum has the benefit that the compiler knows you do not want to accidentally create arbitrary objects. It has the downside that if you want lazy initialisation instead you would need to introduce an additional delegate for the lazily loaded part.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as MyClass is loaded, it will get initialized.But it will initialize only one time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to say that a class gets initialised as soon as it is loaded. A class will only be initialised once a running program creates an instance of that class (by calling its constructor with the new keyword) or once any of the static methods or fields belonging to the class are used.

See the [Java Language Specification section 12.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) for the JVM rules on initialisation.

I should point out that I only know this thanks to the excellent book by Joshua Bloch, "Effective Java, Second Edition". Item 71 offers advice about lazy initialization and the "lazy initialization holder class idiom".

So, in answer to your question, `MyClass.myobj` will only be initialised when a running program (such as your `main()` method) actually makes a call to `MyClass.getMyobj()` and not a moment before then.

And because static fields are only initialised once per class, the next time `MyClass.getMyobj()` is called, it will simply return the existing value for `MyClass.myobj`, so you will get two references to exactly the same MyClass object.